# How to prove this inequation holds?

Tags: linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Let $a, b, u, v \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $av - bu = 1$.

Prove the following inequation:
$$a^2 + b^2 + u^2 + v^2 +au + bv \ge 3$$

The following is a proof for: $a^2 + b^2 + u^2 + v^2 +au + bv \ge 1$

$$\begin{align} a^2 + b^2 + u^2 + v^2 +au + bv \ge 1 \\\\ 2\frac{a^2 + b^2 + u^2 + v^2}{2} + 2\frac{au}{2} + 2\frac{bv}{2} \ge 1 \\\\ \frac{a^2 + 2au + u^2 + b^2 + 2bv + v^2}{2} + \frac{a^2 + b^2 + u^2 + v^2}{2} \ge 1 \\\\ \frac{(a + u)^2 + (b + v)^2}{2} + \frac{a^2 + b^2 + u^2 + v^2}{2} \ge 1 = av - bu \\\\ \frac{(a + u)^2 + (b + v)^2}{2} + \frac{a^2 + b^2 + u^2 + v^2}{2} - 2\frac{bu - av}{2} \ge 0 \\\\ \frac{(a + u)^2 + (b + v)^2}{2} + \frac{a^2 - 2av + v^2 + b^2 + 2bu + u^2}{2} \ge 0 \\\\ \frac{(a + u)^2 + (b + v)^2}{2} + \frac{(a - v)^2 + (b + u)^2}{2} \ge 0 \end{align}$$

The left part of the last inequation is a sum of nonnegative terms so it as a whole is nonnegative, or in other words greater than $0$.

Here's a proof for: $a^2 + b^2 + u^2 + v^2 \ge 2$
$$\begin{align} av - bu = 1 \\\\ 2bu - 2av = -2 \\\\ b^2 + 2bu + u^2 + a^2 - 2av + v^2 = a^2 + b^2 + u^2 + v^2 - 2 \\\\ (b + u)^2 + (a - v)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + u^2 + v^2 - 2 \ge 0 \\\\ (b + u)^2 + (a - v)^2 + 2 = a^2 + b^2 + u^2 + v^2 \ge 2 \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong.

Try $(a,b,u,v)=\left(1,0,\frac{1}{2},1\right).$

We need to prove that:
$$1+\frac{1}{4}+1+\frac{1}{2}\geq3,$$ which is not true.

As said Will Jagy $$\min_{av-bu=1}(a^2+b^2+u^2+v^2+au+bv)=\sqrt3.$$

Indeed, we need to prove that:
$$a^2+b^2+u^2+v^2+au+bv\geq\sqrt3(av-bu)$$ or
$$a^2+(u-\sqrt3v)a+b^2+(v+\sqrt3u)+u^2+v^2\geq0,$$ for which it's enough to prove that $$(u-\sqrt3v)^2-4(b^2+(v+\sqrt3u)+u^2+v^2)\leq0$$ or
$$4b^2+4(v+\sqrt3u)b+v^2+2\sqrt3uv+3u^2\geq0$$ or
$$(2b+v+\sqrt3u)^2\geq0$$ and easy to see that the equality indeed occors.

Comment: the minimum is $\sqrt 3,$  which makes the original question plausible if the only mistake is a missing square root sign. The minimum occurs along a circle in a 2-plane.

Comment: @Will Jagy   Yes, you are right! I have proved it.

Comment: Very good; glad I brought it up. I suggest adding a comment under the question, I am not entirely sure that an edit to an existing answer creates a ping for the OP.